# Do MySQL database transactions break Laravel PHPUnit tests using RefreshDatabase or DatabaseTransactions?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, transactions, phpunit

I'm belatedly writing some PHPUnit feature tests for a project. One of these hits a number of routes which modify the database - and until now, I've been using database transactions in some of these routes.

If I use either the `RefreshDatabase` or `DatabaseTransactions` trait in my test, it fails with a strange error:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\ClassM]
```

If I remove the traits (so the data will persist), the test passes.

I went through and removed all my database transactions from the relevant routes, and the test now *does* pass with `RefreshDatabase`.

My suspicion is that the problem is that MySQL doesn't support nested transactions, and both traits use transactions. But that would mean that if I want to run tests with `RefreshDatabase` (by far the best option!), I can't use transactions at all in my code.

Is that correct? It seems a major limitation.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround - and it seems a little strange. I was mostly using the "manual" transaction methods - e.g.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    $user = User::create([...]); etc.
    DB::commit();
}
catch (...) {
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

I simply switched to the closure method:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $user = User::create([...]); etc.
});
```

No idea why that would have fixed it!